# Fast token overlap between strings

Tags: string, nlp, matching

I have two sets of tokenised sentences `A` and `B` and I want to calculate the overlap between them in terms of common tokens. For example, the overlap between two individual sentences `a1` `today is a good day` and `b1` `today I went to a park` is 2 (`today` and `a`). I need a simple string matching method, without fuzzy or advanced methods. So the result is a matrix between all sentences in A and B with an overlap count for each pair.

The problem is that, while trivial, it is a quadratic operation (size of `A` x size of `B` pair-wise comparisons). With large data, the computation gets very slow very quickly. What would be a smart way of computing this avoiding pair-wise comparisons or doing them very fast? Are there packages/data structures particularly good for this?